# Lebesgue Integration: Double Integral (Fubini)

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to determine whether or not $f$ is integrable on $E$, where $f(x,y) = e^{-xy}$ and $E = \{(x,y) : 0 < x < y < x+x^2\}$

Ok, so $f$ is continuous and non-negative on $E$ so it is measurable. This gives us that

$\displaystyle\int_E f(x,y) \ dx dy = \underbrace{\int_0^{\infty} \left(\int_{x}^{x+x^2}e^{-xy} \ dy\right)dx}_{= J} = \underbrace{\int_{x}^{x+x^2}\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy} \ dx \right) dy}_{= I} $

Then using the RHS of the last equality:

$\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy} \ dx = \dfrac{1}{y}$

So,

$I = \displaystyle\int_{x}^{x+x^2} \dfrac{1}{y} \ dy = \ln(x+x^2)-\ln(x) = \ln(1+x)$

Which obviously doesn't work. What do I need to do here, do the limits on the integrals in $I$ need to be changed so that I have $0 < x < y$ and then $y$ ranging from $0$ to $\infty$?

If so, that gives:

$I = \displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1-e^{-y^2}}{y} \ dy$, which I'm having trouble evaluating (but according to Wolfram, it diverges).

On the other hand, looking at $J$ I get,

$J = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-x^2(1+x)}}{x} \ dx $

Which, according to Wolfram, does converge.

I'm clearly doing something silly here and I'm guessing Fubini's theorem doesn't hold at all, but I can't see why.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your RHS (i.e. $I$) doesn't make sense - you can't just swap the integrals if the range of the inner integral depends on the integration variable of the outter integral....

Comment: Ok, thanks. However that, as I later point out, gives an $I$ and $J$ that don't agree, according to Wolfram.

Comment: @fgp Using $I$ with the correct limits (so $x$ ranging from $0$ to $y$ and $y$ ranging from $0$ to $\infty$) diverges (according to Wolfram) whereas $J$ converges (again, according to Wolfram). Since Fubini holds, this makes no sense (and is why I care, and am confused).

Comment: @Nobe Yeah, sorry for that - I miss-read, and thought that you've determined that $J$ diverges. Still, your limits for $I$ sounds weird... If I fix $y$, $x$ ranges from $\sqrt{y}$ to $y$ AFAICS from a quick sketch. Your integration area is a kind of "trumpet", limited on one side by the line $y=x$ and on the other side by the parabola $y=x^2$.

Comment: @fgp I agree evaluating $J$ makes more sense from how $E$ has been defined. Do you have any idea how to show that $J = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x^2}-e^{-x^2(1+x)}}{x} \ dx < \infty $ to conclude $f$ is integrable on $E$? Thanks again.

Comment: Today's obviously not my best day. I wrote "If I fix $x$, $y$ ranges" in my last comment, but I meant "If I fix $y$, $x$ ranges...". Probably the most confusing typo I could have made - sorry again. Fixed the comment now.

Comment: Re-arranging gives $J = \int_0^\infty f$ with $f(x) = x^{-1}e^{-x^2}(1 - e^{-x^3})$. I'd split that integral in two parts. For small $x$, the troublesome part is $\frac{1}{x}$, but that's dominated by $1 - e^{-x^3}$, which goes to zero fast as $x \to 0$. For large $x$, all terms except $e^{-x^2}$ are bounded from above (by $1$, even!), so the fact that $e^{-x^2}$ is integrable suffices.

Comment: Can't the same logic hold for $I$ too ? And so $I$ converges..

Comment: Is Wolfram being silly ?

Comment: You first have to find the correct $I$. Look at my answer below - you too got the integration limits wrong...

Comment: @Noble. Ok, I hope my answers clears up the confusion - it now explains how to swap the integration order, and how to show that the integral exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if the range of some integral in an interated integration depends on the integration variable of an outter integral, you need to be carefull when swapping the order of integration. In your case, you have $$
  E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,:\, x,y \geq 0, x \leq y \leq x+x^2 \} \text{.}
$$
That area looks like a kind of "trumpet", between the line $y=x$ and the parabola $y=x+x^2$.

---

For a fixed $x$, it's obvious that $y$ ranges from $x$ to $x+x^2$, and hence, as your question correctly states, $$
  \int_E f = \int_0^\infty \int_x^{x+x^2}f(x,y) \,dydx \text{.}
$$
This corresponds to the partitioning $E = \bigcup_{x\in [0,\infty]} \left(\{x\}\times [x,x+x^2]\right)$, i.e. a partitioning of $E$ as a disjoint set of lines parallel to the $y$-Axis. To swap the order of integration, we need to write $E$ as a disjoint union of line segments parallel to the $x$-Axis. If you fix an $y$, for $(x,y$ to lie in $E$ you must have $x \leq y$ and $x+x^2 \geq y$. The second condition is equivalent to $\sqrt{y + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2} \leq x$, and you thus get $$
  E = \bigcup_{x\in [0,\infty]} \left(\left[\sqrt{y + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2},y\right]\times\{y\}\right)
$$
and therefore $$
  \int_E f = \int_0^\infty \int_{\sqrt{y + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2}}^y f(x,y) \,dxdy \text{.}
$$
Not particularly pretty, so it seems easier to use the "obvious" order of integration.

---

If you do that, you get $$
  \int_E e^{-xy} \,d(x,y) = \int_0^\infty g(x) \,dx \text{ where } g(x) = \frac{1}{x}e^{-x^2}\left(1-e^{-x^3}\right)\text{.}
$$
Let's look at $\int_0^1 g$. Then $e^{-x^2} \leq 1$ so $$
  g(x) \leq \frac{1}{x}\left(1-e^{-x^3}\right) \text{.}
$$
Intuitively, that RHS converges if integrated from $0$ to $1$, because $(1-e^{-x^3})$ goes to zero "fast enough" as $x \to 0$. To formalize that, use the taylor series of $e^x$ to expand $1-e^{-x^3} = x^3 - \frac{x^6}{2!} + \frac{x^9}{3!} +\ldots \leq x^3M$ for $x \in [0,1]$. This yields $g(x) \leq x^2M$ and therefore $$
  \int_0^1 g \leq M \text{.}
$$

Then look at $\int_1^\infty g(x)$. This is easier - you can easily find an $M$ such that $g(x) \leq Me^{-x}$ for $x \geq 1$, since you got $e^{-x^n} \leq e^{-x}$ and $x^{-1} \leq 1$ on that interval. Thus, you found a integrable dominating function, so your integral exists.

Thus, the iterated integral exists and is finite, and because $f$ is positive, so is thus the origina integral $\int_E f$.